# UIImageView not clipping to UIView bounds while animating

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

I have a UIImageView in a UICollectionViewCell that I am moving in relation to a scroll views content offset. This is all to provide a parallax effect when the user scrolls horizontally, however there seems to be a clipping issue when the scroll view begins to scroll.

Instead of clipping, the edges persist and are shown outside of the containers boundaries.

The attached screenshot best showcases the behavior...
[image]
In the screen shot the scroll view has begun scrolling right and the accompanying views have begun translating however the UIImageView has not clipped its borders to match the receiver. Which in this case should be the transparent UIView.

Here is the UIImageView

```
let cellImage: UIImageView = {
    let c = UIImageView()
    c.clipsToBounds = true
    c.layer.masksToBounds = true
    c.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    c.image = UIImage(named: "tree")
    c.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    c.layer.cornerRadius = 15
    return c
}()
```

The UIImageView is then added to a containerView and is set to fill it's bounds.

```
cellContainerView.addSubview(cellImage)
//add constraints
```

My thoughts are that if anything this issue may have to do with my interpretation of what the `.clipsToBounds` property does.

The documentation states:

> Setting this value to true causes subviews to be clipped to the bounds
>   of the receiver.

I initially thought the receiver was the view you attached the UIImageView to however that is looking to not be the case.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the documentation states:

> Setting this value to true causes subviews to be clipped to the bounds
>   of the receiver.

Currently you are setting this property on `cellImage` ,so in this case it is the receiver, so its subviews will be clipped. But you want to clip this imageview so I think you need to set this property on `cellContainerView`, since you want its subviews to be clipped.